# How to prevent glob patterns from expanding while splitting colon separated glob patterns by colon?

Tags: shell, posix, glob

Here is my shell script written for POSIX shell. I am aiming at POSIX shell compatibility. There is a `PATTERNS` variable that contains colon separated glob patterns. This variable is a user input. I cannot change this. The rest of the code is my code and I can change it to achieve my purpose. The purpose in the small demo program below is to log (or display) each glob pattern on a separate line.

```
PATTERNS=*.*:*.txt:*.html
IFS=:
for pattern in $PATTERNS
do
    unset IFS
    echo Pattern: "$pattern"
done
```

This is the current working directory.

```
$ ls
a.txt  b.txt  foo.sh
```

When I run the code, I get this output.

```
$ sh foo.sh 
Pattern: a.txt
Pattern: b.txt
Pattern: foo.sh
Pattern: a.txt
Pattern: b.txt
Pattern: *.html
```

Instead of displaying each glob pattern in a line, it is displaying each file that was matched by the glob pattern in a line. Since `*.html` did not match any file in the current directory, only this glob pattern was displayed as desired.

The output I desire is:

```
Pattern: *.*
Pattern: *.txt
Pattern: *.html
```

So I want the glob patterns to be not expanded into the filenames in the current directory. How can I do that? The solution must work fine for any POSIX shell.

Answer (score 0):

Not positive I didn't miss anything or that there isn't a better way but this works isn't using anything I know to be unportable.

```
#!/bin/sh

PAT="*.rc:*.rpms:*.sh"

# Function so we can repeatedly expand the remaining string.
read_next() {
    IFS=: read hd tl <<EOF
$1
EOF
}

tl=$PAT
while read_next "$tl" && [ -n "$hd" ]; do
    echo "Pattern: $hd"
done
```

Alternatively, and this is simpler, though it requires the "global" `IFS` modification which I am never a fan of (I greatly prefer the scoped `IFS` modification on `read`) as well as modifying global shell settings you could simply disable pathname expansion entirely with the `-f` flag to [`set`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set) (and then re-enable it with `set +f` afterwards if desired) and then just keep your original loop.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed response with code example. Did you consider using `set +f` to disable glob expansion? Do you see any problems using this? It seems to be defined in POSIX at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set.

Comment: I did. I meant to check for and then mention that actually but apparently forgot to do so.